# How can I estimate $A(q)y(t) = B(q)u(t) + C(q)e(t)$?

Tags: control-theory, least-squares, parameter-estimation, linear-control, adaptive-control

How can I estimate the model

$$A(q)y(t) = B(q)u(t) + C(q)e(t)$$

Where $e(t)$ is the noise and $u(t)$ is input and $y(t)$ is output of the model? I don't know how to find the $e(t)$ noise.

Notice that the kalman gain matix $K$ can be found from:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-a_1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots  &  & \ddots  & & \\ 
 -a_{n-1}& 0 &  &\cdots  & 1 \\ 
-a_n &0  &  &\cdots  & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \dots & 0  &b_0  & \dots & b_m
\end{bmatrix}^T
$$

$$
\bar C = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &\dots  &0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
K = \begin{bmatrix}
c_1 -a_1 &  \dots & c_n-a_n 
\end{bmatrix}^T$$

Because $det(qI - A + K \bar C) = C(q)$

**Source:**

Adaptive Control by Karl Johan Åström - Second edition. Page 166.

Comment: Sorry, it is not really clear. Do you assume that the parameters $A$, $B$ and $C$ are known, and you want to estimate the unmeasured external signal $e(t)$? Then try to search for "Input observer". Or you want to estimate the parameters $A$, $B$, and $C$ from the history of $y(t)$ and $u(t)$? Then I guess that the answer should be in the book you cite.

Comment: @Arastas I want to estimate $A, B, C$ from $y, u$.

Comment: What you want to do is the ARMAX identification. It is a nice topic. If you are a Matlab user, you can start here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/armax.html
Or you can google for ARMAX identification, there are some results and papers.

Comment: @Arastas Sorry. Only GNU Octave. Can this model above be used for both stochastical systems and deterministic systems?